# Google API - Access Permission Content

Tags: google-api, google-drive-picker

We are using the Google API to upload the files from the Google drive. Before entering into Google Drive, we asking the access permission popup to show the some content. In this case, we have used the auth scope as https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file.

From the attached image, you provided the content as to delete the files. But, we couldn't able to delete the file once entered into the Google Drive.

[image]

My question is to remove the Delete content from the Access Permission popup.

Comment: please edit your question and include your code.   What file are you trying to delete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

It is not possible to remove the possibility to remove files from the scope. There is a [list](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#drive) of the available scopes for Google Drive and you have to choose at least one from there.